# In Rails 1.2.x, how do we override default document root (public) directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to define a different document root to one of my rails 1.2.3 application. By default rails uses public directory as its document root. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Rails 1.x? Really? This stuff is ancient!

Comment: Yes I agree. But this has to be done.

Comment: Please explain why you want to change this.

Comment: @Ryan, the application is too complicated and is writing files into directories under public which are not supposed to be accessible to public. And this is hardcoded in too many places making it hard to change the path in all the places.

Also there is a requirement to make only few js and css files to be accessed directly and the rest of them via controller action by authenticating the request.

Hence I thought it will be good to change the document root directory to something like public_unrestricted and move directly accessible files to this directory and render others from controller

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you are fighting Rails conventions which is a Really Bad Idea(tm). Please just go through the application and change the paths where the code is writing to public to write to other directories. Sometimes, this is what you have to do within the field of software development.